# Trying to return multiple data only once

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have an object which are translate positions & I them in my transform function here:

```
   .attr("transform", function(d,i)
                {return "translate ("+ arc[i].centroid() +")" +  inner[d.Country];})
                ;


   .text(function(d) {return d.Country;})
```

I would like to know whether it is possible to define in the text function to only collect the country data once & not multiple times?

Heres a jsfiddle to make my point more clear:http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/41/

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To draw the country name you are iterating over the nodes, which have repeated country names, hence you are getting the multiple names.  Perhaps you could do a quick transformation on nodes and iterate over that.  Something like this could work.

First create a function that returns unique elements.  This is one I found in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array):

```
function unique(a) {
  var s = a.sort();
  var r = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    if (s[i + 1] != s[i]) {
      r.push(s[i]);
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

And then use the following as your data element.

```
unique(nodes.map(function(d) { return d.Country }))
```

What this does is, first, convert the nodes array into an array of country names and, second,  get only the non repeated country names.  You would have to change your functions in presence to remove the `d.Country` since the data is now in `d`.

Hope it helps...